# Subtract two values from current row cells and output that value into a new cell row (google script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am making a Google Sheet that will track clock in-out times. I want to add a column e that will calculate the number of hours worked given the start time (column c) and end time (column d). How can I go about implementing this? Here is my code:

```
function setValue(cellName, value){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}

function getValue(cellName){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue();
}
function getNextRow(){
  return getCurrentRow() + 1;
}
function getCurrentRow(){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow();
}
function addStart(a, b, c, d){
  var row = getNextRow();
  setValue('A' + row, a); // employee name row
  setValue('B' + row, b); // date row
  setValue('C' + row, c); // clock in time row
}
function addEnd(endTime) {
  var row = getCurrentRow();
  setValue('D' + row, endTime); // 
}
function updateRow(e){
  // declare row e
  var row = getCurrentRow();
  setValue('E' + row, e) 
}

function punchIn(){
  addStart("Faiq Ashraf", new Date(), date(), "")
}
function punchOut(){
  addEnd(date());
}
function totalHours(){
  // function used to update column e with our total hours worked
  var total = getCurrentRow().addEnd(d) - getCurrentRow().addStart(c)
  updateRow(total);
}
function date(){
  var dd = new Date();
  var currentTime = dd.toLocaleTimeString();
  return currentTime
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually use a solution currently in Google sheets that I made for this exact purpose, and you don't need to use custom functions at all.

Just put the following function in row E in your example:

```
=Hour(D1-C1)+(Minute(D1-C1)/60)
```

Comment: It says that hour is not defined, is there a function that I need to import?

Comment: No, that is a stock google sheets function https://sheetshelp.com/hour/